# Is Facebook Sharing with Prefilled Text Not allowed?

Tags: facebook, sharing

i want to share text on facebook with SLComposeViewController but its not providing sharing pre filled text , its working with ios 9.2 simulator , but not working in ios 9.3.
so please suggest any alternative solution for that.
thanks

Comment: Actually you cannot share pre-filled text with facebook. That facility is removed by facebook. You can share image, video only.

Comment: Have you read the Facebook Platform Policy? I assume not

Comment: funny enough you can still pre-fill an image - how about making a screenshot of the text and pre-fill that image ;-) ?